# Assistance with getting the pipe in my c shell working

Tags: c, linux, shell

Hi I need some assistance with my pipe method I created for my c shell. I am trying to get it to run a simple ls | wc.

I have written a method called `createPipe` which forks two child processes, because the standard output of cmd1 becomes the standard input of cmd2.

I have also written a method called `execute()` which is supposed to split the paths  we have to maintain a constant path variable) and to `execv` the path and the commands, I have to use `execv`, instead of `execvp` or `execlp` etc.

When I execute my program in the part of `createPipe` where it hits `execute(command)`, I keep getting that ls | wc is an invalid command.

If I attempt to just `execv` the commands in the `createPipe` method instead of using the `execute` method, It hits an error I inserted into my method, so I get:

```
no exec child1: bad address
```

I am not sure what is wrong. If something is incorrect in my `createPipe` method, or if something is wrong in my `execute` method, or I am not handling things correctly in my `main` program. Another opinion would really help.

Here is my code:

```
/* main.c */

#define NUM_ARGS 10
#define BUF_SIZE 128

void utility(char *array[]);

void cleararray(char *array[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(array[i]!=NULL)
    {
        array[i]=NULL;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void){

    int redir_Flag=0;
    int i=0,j;
    char str[BUF_SIZE];
    char *p;
    char *array[NUM_ARGS];

    do
    {
        cleararray(array);
        printf("~MyShell $:");
        i=0;
        fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
        p=strtok(str," \n");
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            array[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(p));
            strcpy(array[i],p); 
            p=strtok (NULL," \n");
            i++;
            array[i]=NULL;
        }

        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(strcmp(array[j],">")==0)
            {
                array[j]=NULL;
                redirect(array,array[j+1]);
                redir_Flag=1;
                break;
            }
            //printf("%s %d\n",array[j],j);
       }
       //printf("Before flag checking :%s\n",array[0]);
       /////////////////////////////////////////////  beginning of pipe check
       int q;
       for(q=0; q < i; q++){
           if(strcmp(array[q], "|") == 0)
           {
               printf("%s %s\n", array[q-1], array[q+1]);
               //char **cmda=NULL;
               //char **cmdb=NULL;
               createPipe(array[q-1], array[q+1]);
           }
       }
       if(redir_Flag==1)
       {
           redir_Flag=0;
           continue;
       }
       else{}
       if(array[0]==NULL){continue;}
       else if(strcmp(array[0],"exit")==0)
       {
           break;
       }
       else if(strcmp(array[0],"cd")==0)
       {
           change_Dir(array[1]);
       }
       else if(strcmp(array[0],"path")==0)
       {
           if(array[1]==NULL)
           {
               print_path();
           }
           else if(strcmp(array[1],"+")==0)
           {
               add_path(array[2]);
           }
           else if(strcmp(array[1],"-")==0)
           {
               remove_path(array[2]);
           }
           else {printf("invalid command\n");}
       }
       else if(array[0]==NULL){continue;}
       else
       {
           utility(array);
       }
       i=0;
       fflush(stdout);
       cleararray(array);
   }while(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Pipe.c

```
void createPipe(char **cmd1, char **cmd2){

    pid_t pid1; 
    pid_t pid2;

    int newPipefd[2];

    if(pipe(newPipefd)== -1){
        perror("pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid1 = fork();
    if(pid1 == -1){
        perror("fork error");
    }
    else if(pid1==0){
        //first child process closes the read end dup write
        close(1);
        dup(newPipefd[1]);
        close(newPipefd[1]);
        close(newPipefd[0]);

        execute(cmd1);     ////////////////////////here is where I have issues
        execv(cmd1[0], cmd1);

        perror("no exec child1");
    }
    else{
        pid2 = fork();
        if(pid2 ==-1){
            perror("fork error");
    }
    else if (pid2 == 0){
        //second child process closes up write side of pipe and dup read
        close(0);
        dup(newPipefd[0]);
        close(newPipefd[0]);
        close(newPipefd[1]);

        execute(cmd2);
        execv(cmd2[0], cmd2);
    } else {
        //parent
        int status;
        close(newPipefd[0]);
        close(newPipefd[1]);
        waitpid(pid1, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        waitpid(pid2, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
    }
}
```

`execute` method

```
void execute(char *arg[]){
    int j=0,k;
    char *p;
    char *array[NUM_ENV];
    if(access(arg[0],F_OK)==0)
    {
        execv(arg[0],arg);
    }
    else
    {
        p=strtok(path,":\n");
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            array[j]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(p));
            strcpy(array[j],p);
            p=strtok (NULL,":\n");
            printf("%s\n",array[j]);
            j++;
            array[j]=NULL;
        }
        for(k=0;k<j;k++){
            printf("in for loop : %s\n",arg[k]);
            strcat(array[k],"/");
            strcat(array[k],arg[0]);
            printf("IN FOR LOOP, ARRAY IS :%s\n",array[k]);

            if(access(array[k],F_OK)==0)
            {
                execv(array[k],arg);
            }
        }
        printf("Invalid command\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to reindent your code because you use tabs and very inconsistent style.  Both of these are bad habits.  Tabs should be avoided because they cause code to be misaligned when moved from one environment (your editor) to another (mine, S.O. code fragment boxes...).   Inconsistent style makes the code hard to read for everyone, including you, giving bugs many more places to hide in plain sight.

Comment: Note that error messages such as `printf("Invalid command\n");` should be printed on the standard error channel, not on standard output.  Use: `fprintf(stderr, "Invalid command\n");` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I can see some problems in your code.  For one, this is a bug:

```
 array[j]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(p));
 strcpy(array[j],p);
```

You allocate space for a pointer, not for a copy of the string. Replace these lines with:

```
 array[j] = strdup(p);
```

In the `for` loop, you cannot do this:

```
 strcat(array[k],"/");
 strcat(array[k],arg[0]);
```

because `array[k]` does not have extra room for the strings you tack at the end.  You should realloc `array[k]`, which means you need to allocate all arguments so you don't end up leaking memory nor mixing allocated arguments and unallocated ones, albeit it may not matter much since you quickly call `exec`.

There are probably more problems...

Comment: Agreed. Except may be good to also explain why the malloc is a bug as it may not be obious to the OP.